# $state.go() clears $historyStack in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

In **Ionic** I got a slider in one tab. On click on a slide I want to jump to a subpage on another tab. I achieve that using

```
$state.go('^.station', {stationId:clickedSlide});
```

I get to view alright, but there is no back button to the root view (**.stationen**) of this tab. It seems to clear the entire historyStack of this tab. Even if I try to first jump to **.stationen** first and then to **.station** I do not get a back button.

My stateProvider looks like so:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.map', {
    url: '/map',
    views: {
      'tab-map': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-map.html',
        controller: 'MapController'
      }
    }
  })
   .state('tab.stationen', {
              url: '/stationen',
       views: {
        'tab-stationen': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-stationen.html',
            controller: 'StationenCtrl'
        }
       }
    })
    .state('tab.station', {
      url: '/stationen/:stationId',
      views: {
        'tab-stationen': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-station.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/map');

});
```

I tried setting options in my **$state.go()** call but to no avail. Also nesting the **.station** in **.stationen** did not get me any results. What am I missing?

Comment: "to a subpage on another tab ... but there is no back button to the root view (.stationen) of this tab" - are you expecting a back button from the new tab to the old tab? each tab has its own root and history

Comment: no, each tab has a primary view. For my stationen-tab this is tab.stationen. Content-wise tab.stationen holds a ion-list of buttons and tab.station should display the details once one of these buttons was pressed.
So as I use the tab and tap a list-item everything works fine. There is a backButton leading back to the list. If I however jump from another tab (tab.map) directly to tab.station, I do not get this backButton, even if I opened tab.stationen beforehand and it definitely was set as view in the historyStack of my stationen-tab.